# Implementing facebook login in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use Facebook's Javascript SDK to implement a login button in a Chrome extension's `popup.html` page.

However when I call the `FB.login()` function, I get the following error: `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration`. Now, since it's a Chrome extension, I am not sure if I can provide a URL or domain for it.

So, what should I do in such a case?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849496/using-facebook-sdk-with-chrome-extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually build the login flow, as it is explained here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2

I'm building a login button for a chrome extension too, and I followed those instructions. However, whenever I try to access, I get this:

"Success
"SECURITY WARNING. Please use the url above as you would your password and do not share It with anyone."

This *should* be the right way... but *I* can't make It work. Maybe you can.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. In the 'Advanced' tab of App settings, select 'Yes' the `Native or desktop app?` and `Embedded browser OAuth Login` options.

Comment: I keep getting warning... but I managed to manually retrieve the token before I get redirected to the warning url.

Comment: What should be put in redirect_uri parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to add fb-login feature in my chrome extension. I am using python-socialauth as authentication app for facebook in django app, which is the backend.

The steps I followed is as given below :

First I opened a window with facebook login link :

window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&response_type=token&redirect_uri=,"Facebook login", "width=635,height=290,left=0,top=0")

From the success url, I retrieved the access token and saved in chrome-local-storage.

Then I sent the token to my django-facebook-login view. But it is hitting error:

```
'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'encode'.
```

My code is as below :

```
if isinstance(request.backend, BaseOAuth1):
        if request.REQUEST.get('backend') == "facebook":
            oauth_token_secret = settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY
        if request.REQUEST.get('backend') == "google-oauth2":
            oauth_token_secret = settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET
        token = {
            'oauth_token': request.REQUEST.get('access_token'),
            'oauth_token_secret': oauth_token_secret,
        }
    elif isinstance(request.backend, BaseOAuth2):
        token = request.REQUEST.get('access_token')
    else:
        raise HttpResponseBadRequest('Wrong backend type')

    user = request.backend.do_auth(token, ajax=True)
    # age = request.POST.get('age', '')
    login(request, user)
```

The line where I am hitting error is :
    user = request.backend.do_auth(token, ajax=True)