# The Facebook JavaScript SDK does not work on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I am writing up a chrome extension. The functionality of the extension includes the Facebook login. The extension does not support external JavaScript links so for that I had to make "content_security_policy" in the manifest file of extension. And now it works, it is loading the external file of Facebook SDK. The problem I am facing now is; while creating the app in Facebook developers account, I gave the domain and URL as **http://localhost.com/** and when I run SDK script on my extension it shows an error which is :

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

And when I load the URL it shows me the link :

**`chrome-extension://hpkkicffiddlopkeiobamkfhfbbofmel/index.html`**

By placing this URL in the Facebook developers app, it giving me invalidity error. What should I do now?

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849496/using-facebook-sdk-with-chrome-extensions) question is similar.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Verifiable and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code to replicate the error. If the nature of your question is such that you can't do that, it is outside the scope of SO.

Comment: @MoshFeu the second problem isnt solved. The url one

Comment: @Tijmen i am making  a chrome extension which in which i am saving the user public profile info in database. To access facebook API I was required to setup the app in developer.facebook.com, and there i put the URL as http:localhost.com and domain name as localhost.com but now the url of the extension is different and it is showing me error which i have highlighted, i dont know which protocol should it follow in the app to use this

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the JavaScript SDK for OAuth logins in a Chrome extension because of this limitation - you can't redirect to an extension page.

You can use [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity), which gives a non-`chrome-extension:` virtual URL that is OK to use with Facebook. That will give you the token to use with other Facebook APIs.

There's example code [here](https://github.com/blackgirl/Facebook_Oauth2_sample_for_extensions).

Alternatively, you can do [the whole OAuth flow manually](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0).

Comment: basically i am not using it for login, i just need some info and that is what i am getting, but i am facing that problem and i dont know how to overcome that now

Comment: Presumably you need an access token, still.

Comment: the getRedirectURL can help me